# position two divs with position fixed after each other without setting explicit heights

Tags: html, css

With the snippet below I would like to have the fixed divs appear in the screenshot below preferably without having to set an explicit height or margin-top because if I do that, I will need different heights at different breakpoints and I don't want to use javascript.

[image]

Is it possible to stack `position: fixed` divs in this way without explicit heights or margin-top?

```css
body {
  text-rendering: optimizespeed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "header" auto
    "main" 1fr
    "footer" auto / 1fr;
}

.scroller {
  height: 150vh;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 10px solid red;
}

main {
  position: relative;
}

.ours {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.third-party {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "leading center trailing";
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <header class="ours">Should be no.1</header>
      <main>
        <div class="third-party">
          <header>should be no.2</header>
        </div>
        <div class="scroller">
          scroller should come after 2
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap div one and two with another div and apply `position:sticky` to it with `top:0`

Sample:

```css
.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.scroll {
  height: 800px;
  border: 2px dashed;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </div>
    <div class="two">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll"> Something in scroll div </div>
</div>
```